# Hide output from when mouseover Locator graphic

Tags: locator

When the mouse pointer passes over the Locator graphic (or one clicks at any point in the frame), the underlying equation that generates the `ContourPlot` is visible in a text box. How can I suppress this output? Here is the code.

```
Manipulate[
iv = Row[{"t0 = " , N[p[[1]], 3], ", ", "x0 = " , N[p[[1]], 3]}];

 ContourPlot[(x - t - 1) Exp[x - p[[2]]] == 
   p[[2]] - p[[1]] - 1, {t, -6, 6}, {x, -6, 6}, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}, 
  FrameLabel -> {t, x}, RotateLabel -> False, 
  ContourStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick],
  Epilog -> {Point[p], Text[iv]}
  ],
 {{p, {-2, -2}}, {-10, -10}, {10, 10}, Locator,
  Appearance -> Graphics[{Blue, Disk[{0, 0}, .1]}, ImageSize -> 14]}]
```

Comment: You have syntax error. ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5fGn0.png)

Comment: You misssbellling the word Manipulate in the code above.

Comment: Thanks Nasser but the spelling of Manipulate is not the problem.

Comment: thanks for correcting the spelling. Yes I know it was not the problem, but for futures visitors so they do not have to think it is a new command or something when they look at the code.

Comment: @Stephen Your last edit cut the question from the text.  I put it back.  Make sure it's what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `CountourLabels-> None`:

```
Manipulate[

 iv = Row[{"t0 = ", N[p[[1]], 3], ", ", "x0 = ", N[p[[1]], 3]}];
 ContourPlot[(x - t - 1) Exp[x - p[[2]]] ==  p[[2]] - p[[1]] - 1, {t, -6, 6}, {x, -6, 6}, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}, 
  FrameLabel -> {t, x}, ContourStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], ContourLabels -> None, 
  Epilog -> {Point[p], Text[iv]}], {{p, {-2, -2}}, {-10, -10}, {10, 10}, Locator, 
  Appearance -> Graphics[{Blue, Disk[{0, 0}, .1]}, ImageSize -> 14]}]
```

Comment: My bad> I left ut the opening Manipulate command. See edited code

Comment: @Stephen Have you checked my code?

Comment: I confirmed your code. It works. V 9.01,  No output when mouseover.

Comment: @Nasser Thanks!

Comment: belisarius - I hadn't noticed your addition to the code. It works nicely now.